# Server / client app with webpack + socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, webpack

I'm working on an app that has frontend communicating with backend via socket.io

Right now I have them in two separate apps like this:

```
.
├──client
│  ├──src
│  │  └──index.js
│  ├──public 
│  │  └──index.html
│  ├──webpack.config.js
│  └──package.json
└──server
   ├──app.js
   └──package.json
```

./server/app.js goes like this

```
const Express = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(Express);
const options = {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
        methods: ['GET','POST'],
        credentials: true,
    },
};
const Socketio = require('socket.io')(server, options);

Socketio.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('do-something', () => {
        console.log('doing something...');
    });

});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

./client/src/index.js has these lines

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

const someFunction = () => {
    socket.emit('do-something');
}
```

Pretty standard stuff.

Right now I run them separately from two terminal windows. So basically I have two servers serving a single app. It doesn't seem like the right way to go so I want to try and unite them into a single webpack app to aim for deployment. How do I do that? How do you setup this kind of thing in a real world?

I tried googling on the subject but couldn't find anything. If you know of a post that clearly explains this, share the link please.

Comment: This is an opinion question, and as such unsuitable for SO. I would google for "monorepo vs not" to get a feel for the tradeoffs.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion @JaredSmith, I will google that. It's not an opinion question though, I really don't know how to do this

Comment: `But it is my understanding that I should try and unite them into a single webpack app to aim for deployment. Or should I leave them like this?` This will lead to oppinion based answers because everyone will have a different oppinion on this

Comment: @vch there are lots of different ways to do that, and lots of opinions about whether or not you should in the first place. So by SO standards it's opinion-based.

Comment: Ok guys, I will edit that part so it's less opinion oriented

Comment: @JaredSmith correct me if I'm wrong but isn't create-react-app responsible for only the front end side of things? I mean I've used create-react-app in the past, and I don't see how it's connected with the current issue here. Unless you mean I should look at something specific?

Comment: @vch nvm on the link that was my bad. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend:

1. Placing webpack.config.js and package.json in the root of your project.
2. In ./server, distinguished app.js (export express app) and server.js (listen at a port).
3. Use [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) for simplify your package.json scripts (that provided the commands run-p and run-s)
4. Add a production ./server.js in the root of your project.

./package.json

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "run-p dev:*",
    "dev:server": "nodemon ./server/server.js",
    "dev:webpack": "webpack serve",
    "build:webpack": "webpack",
    "serve": "node ./server.js"
  }
```

./server/app.js

```js
const Express = require('express')();
const app = require('http').Server(Express);

// Your app definition (socket.io, etc) ...

module.exports = app
```

./server/server.js

```js
// Your api dev server

const app = require('./app')

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Dev server listening on port 3000');
});
```

./server.js

```
// Your prod server

const express = require('express')
const app = require('./server/app')

// Same of your api dev server, but your also serve your frontend build
// ./dist depends on webpack "output-path" parameter
app.use(express.static('./dist')) 

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Prod server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Now, you can:

Run frontend and backend in parallel

```sh
npm run dev
```

Run only frontend

```sh
npm run dev:webpack
```

Run only backend

```sh
npm run dev:server
```

Build frontend

```sh
npm run build:webpack
```

Serve backend and frontend in production (I suggest use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/))

```sh
npm run serve
```

This architecture works fine in my projects .
You can easily extend it to use Typescript for example...

Sorry for my aproximativ English.

> I did not test the code presented, sorry if there are any errors.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example, it actually clears up some things for me. I completely overlooked `app.use()`. So you're saying that, when it comes to production, you build the *./client/* and then just host *./server.js*, *./dist/*, and *./server/app.js* on a single server, making *./serve.js* responsible for back-end and also serving front-end, right?

Comment: Exactly ! Abstracting the express app allows you to make it available wherever you want. Be careful with routing when using `app.use('/ sub-api', subApi)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I will study express a little deeper

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I give up. I'm answering.

Don't do this. Right now, merging the two repos looks tempting because you're using the same language and maybe some of the same dependencies for the client and the server.

But what happens when

- Your boss says you have to port the server part to Python/Java/Go/whatever because reasons?
- You want to hand off the client or the server to another team?
- You want to open source the client but now the git history has all of your (still proprietary) server code tangled up in it?
- You add a CI/CD workflow and now a commit to the client kicks off your pipeline for the server and vice-versa?

N.B. this isn't hypothetical, I've actually seen most of those happen. Now, you may have good answers to all those questions and decide to do it anyway, but if you don't then leave it be: bundling a client and server in the same repo loses you lots of flexibility for *very* minimal gains.

Comment: Aha, I see your point. And you're right I don't have good answers to those questions, so I guess I'm leaving it as it is then. I had a feeling that this instinct of mine might be wrong, so that's why I had the "should I do this?" part in the original post in the first place. Thanks for letting me know it's ok as it is.

Comment: However what I meant in the question (and it's probably my bad for not making it clear enough) is not just should I drag contents of one folder into the other, but how do I make it work once it's ready for deployment?

Like, now I'm imagining, one day I will run `npm run build` in my client repo, and what then? How do I host this? Should I actually host this on two separate servers? That's what confuses me, and that's what made me think of merging the repos in the first place.

Sorry for the text wall

Comment: @vch it depends. Usually when I do this sort of thing I don't have any choice about the client details: the target client is a web browser, or a stripped down linux system running on e.g. a raspberry pi in a field device, or a stripped-down linux running in a docker container, or whatever. If this is really two servers where one just listens to the other then you'll have separate build processes for both.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light upon this. I didn't know it was common practice to host frontend and backend separately. However I understand the pros ow this approach for large & complex applications. But is it as justified for smaller applications?

Comment: @vch in a word, yes. Or rather, it should be the *default*, IMO it is the "lets use a monorepo" folks who should be justifying why you need one. For work I currently work on a custom web server that does hybrid SSR for React apps (written before next.js et al) that's in a monorepo, and it is... well, let's just say I hope we're getting a big benefit because the costs are non-trivial. But even in smaller projects, I've almost always ended up regretting it.

Comment: Now that I think about it from this perspective, I actually like the idea of keeping things separated, it feels more controllable in a sense. But it also feels like more work setting up, and more $$ to spend on hosting. And, as much as I agree with your idea, for free projects like the one I'm working on, spending extra money just for the sake of sharing the app with the world, doesn't really feel worth it. Do you think what the other answer suggests with express' `app.use(frontend)` is bad practice?

Comment: @vch it depends. Sometimes you just have to go with it and see what happens.